# Question about estimating a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $t$ be a positive real number, with $x$ running over the standard lattice points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, is it true that $\sum_{|x| > t} t^{-5} = O(t^{-3})$? If so why?

Comment: Is $x$ an integer? A positive integer?

Comment: I consider $x$ to be a lattice point in the standard lattice. I edited the question slightly so that it should make sense now.

Comment: what dimension is your "standard lattice?"

Comment: If $x$ ranges over the integers, the sum is $0$.

Comment: @yoyo: The lattice points should be in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, I have edited the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: compare to something like $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_t^{\infty}r^{-5}rdrd\theta=2\pi t^{-3}/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we suppose that $t$ is bigger than 1, say, then we can approximate half of our sum with the integral $\displaystyle \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{x^5} = \frac{1}{4 t^4}$, and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{t^4} \in O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)$.

**EDIT (now that I know it's over a lattice)**

Do what I did for one dimension above, but in two dimensions. $\displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{r^5} r dr d\theta$ will do if you like polar coordinates.

Comment: The sum is over a lattice in $\mathbb R^2$, so you need a double integral to approximate it.

Comment: Oh - a lattice now. Ok.